# Spring 4 WebSockect over STOMP Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm developing a multiplayer game based on Spring 4 WebSocket.
my server is stateless so in order to identify players i use tokens.

after struggling for sometime with how to identify players over WebSockets i came up with this solution: on the client player registers like this:

```
var sockjs = new SockJS("http://mygame/games/", null, {server : token});
```

this adds the token to the url, I have set up a filter using spring security:

```
String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
String[] parts = StringUtils.split(requestURI, "/");
if (parts.length == 4) {
    String token = parts[1];
   List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
   authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.ROLE_MULTIPLAYER)));
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(token, "MULTIPLAYER", authorities));
}
```

and it works! in all WebSockets requests i have a Principal set.

However some browsers seems to not support this, in **Safari** for example the Principal is not set, when debugging the request i see that the URL is correct and the filter works but the Principal is not set. same goes for IE, Chrome and FF works.
I'm using STOMP (https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket) as a messege protocol.

why is there a different behaviour between the browsers?
is it a Spring or Client issue?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing that too.

Also: how to handle it if using plain websockets without using SockJS?

Comment: can you tell me where you use your sample code?